# How to drop and re-populate mysql databases?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with 10 tables and need to drop and repopulate the database to run some performance tests. Using mysqldump, I can dump out the data.
What steps should I follow next, to clear the database, and re-import? Will need to run this for different sizes of the database (i.e. tables with different number of rows) to calculate the db performance, so I need to make sure these steps can be replicated.

Comment: mysqldump can include the full DDL, including drop statements to kill previous installs of a table.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at the options on `mysqldump` such as `--add-drop-database` and `--add-drop-table`. I'd probably go for `--add-drop-database` in this case.

Comment: Just for interests sake, would you have to re-grant user permissions if using --add-drop-database ?

Answer (score 1):

1) take the dump

```
    drop database db_name
    create database db_name
    mysql -u user -p db_name < dump.sql
```

I am sure this can be repeated any number of times. Its idempotent

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL console:

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE [dbName]; 
mysql> CREATE DATABASE [dbName];
mysql> USE [dbName];
mysql> SOURCE [pathToSQLDump];
```